# Wrap classes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to integrate a package in Laravel 5, is this one:  https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client

I'm just starting with Laravel 5 so I'm not sure what's the best way to add this into the framework, 
Could someone give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: I found that using Laravel with composer packages is dead simple, just adding the USE statement asking for the namespace of the package and you're done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that using Laravel with composer packages is dead simple, just adding the USE statement asking for the namespace of the package and you're done. So I don't need this answer anymore, I still need to know how to integrate a library into Laravel 5, but will be in my TODO list.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OAuth with Facebook, Twitter, Google or Github - then Laravel 5 has [Socialite](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication) built in and will handle all of this for you.

Github repository: https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Comment: Thanks! But I'm building my own API and want to be able to access to that. Maybe I can implement that class with my own service, will take a look. Thanks!